# Vue не реагирует на изменения объекта

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Я тут учу vue и пишу простенький магазин для практики.
И не могу понять почему не обновляется корзина, то есть обновляется объект cart, но в разметке не выводится. 
Знаю что туго объясняю...

```
data: {
    goods: goods,
    cart: {} // не обновляется в разметке...
}
```

Можете посмотреть, там мало кода https://jsfiddle.net/28pegb9n/2/

Comment: Просто заранее объяви содержимое объекта cart и всё, если массив, то содержимое объявлять необязательно. Либо используй Vue.set/this.$set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то это связано с тем, что **Vue** не может отследить добавление или удаление свойств реактивного объекта.

Для добавления свойств в реактивный объект необходимо использовать [Vue.set( target, key, value )](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

В вашем коде:

```
this.$set(this.cart, index, {
    id: index,
    name: this.goods[index].name,
    price: this.goods[index].price,
    img: this.goods[index].img,
    number: 1
});
```

[JSfiddle с изменениями](https://jsfiddle.net/28pegb9n/44/)

Comment: Спасибо, помогли! =)